# How to return the result of individual work item handlers after their completion

Tags: jbpm

please help me i am new to jbpm, everything is working fine for me but i want to return my "result" output parameter upon completion of my individual work item handlers, this is my code.

```
public void CreateCompute(String body) throws Exception
    {
        KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBaseForCompute();
        AssignTEPIPOnHypervisor tepIP = new AssignTEPIPOnHypervisor();
        CreateIntegratedBridgeOnHost IB = new CreateIntegratedBridgeOnHost();
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("AssignTEPIPToHypervisors", tepIP);
        ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("CreateIBOnHosts", IB);
        System.out.println(" >>> Let's create a Persistent Knowledge Session");
        Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("payload", body);
        params.put("session_id",Integer.toString(ksession.getId()));
        System.out.println(">>> Let's Start the Process");
        ksession.startProcess("com.cl.cloud.createcompute", params);
        System.out.println(">>> Disposing Session");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a `return` statement .

Comment: because i don't know what there is to return :(

Answer (score 0):

in the classes implementing WorkItemHandler you have the method:
void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem,
                         WorkItemManager manager);

The workItemManager has a method:

void completeWorkItem(long id,
                          Map results);

Those results are the one returning from your workItem execution. 
Those results will be mapped to process variables according with your data input/output mappings writting in your BPMN2 process. In this case you need to make sure that the dataOutput mappings are correct, and you will see how your process variables are updated.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloProcessExtension implements WorkItemHandler {


public void abortWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
    System.out.println("--> HelloProcessExtension.abortWorkItem()...");
    manager.abortWorkItem(workItem.getId());
}

public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
    System.out.println("--> HelloProcessExtension.executeWorkItem()...");
    System.out.println(workItem.getParameter("param1") + "\n"
    + workItem.getParameter("param2") + "\n"
    + workItem.getParameter("param3"));
    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    results.put("price", new Integer(10));
    System.out.println("--> HelloProcessExtension.executeWorkItem()... sent reults");
    manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), results);
}
}
```

The map contains the key `price`, this key name should be an input or output variable name in your task. the variable `price` in your task, should be mapped to a Process variable.